# Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [localhost:27018,localhost:27019,localhost:30000]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-replication

I am using database connection string like below

```
mongodb://localhost:27018,localhost:27019,localhost:30000/db_name?auto_reconnect=true&poolSize=25&readPreference=secondary&w=1&wtimeout=3000
```

3 mongodb instance is running at a time, but when i try connect using node.js it failed to connect.

Error:

> Error connecting to database: failed to connect to
>   [localhost:27018,localhost:27019,localhost:30000]

Comment: Please see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html. It may be of some help. It describes how to connect to multiple mongos

Comment: If i give only localhost:27018 or localhost:27019 then it will able to connect. it looks like if i give port number which is currently Primary then it will works fine, but i want to give all port at a time so when one mongodb instance is down it will connect to another(secondary become primary).

Comment: Exactly. The "connect to multiple instances" command is different than the one used in a "connect to single instance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to answer if anyone facing same problem.
I have updated my connect-mongo to ~0.8.0 and it works for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html...

Try

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongosA:27501,mongosB:27501', { mongos: true }, cb);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Actually problem is with mongo Store (session), I have updated my connect-mongo package from 0.4.0 to 0.8.1 and its working fine now.